# Delayed Job job table locks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, postgresql-9.1

**UPDATE 3**
Hm,...i was using an old, old, version of delayed_job_active_record. All is well.

I have implemented a push notification service in an API i'm working on. I process the push notifications using delayed job. My problem is that sometimes it seems that the worker process don't obtain a lock on the job table. That is, 2 workers sometimes pick up the same job. I can't reproduce the problem consistently, but i'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this? Here is the code for enqueueing jobs:

```
Device.where("platform = ? AND enabled = ?", 'ios', true ).find_in_batches( batch_size: 2000 ) do |batch| 
    Delayed::Job.enqueue APNWorker.new( params[:push_notification], batch )
end
```

devices is a table containing mobile device tokens. Testing is done locally with Foreman.

**UPDATE 1**
Here is some output from Foreman

```
13:10:41 worker.1 | started with pid 2489
13:10:41 worker.2 | started with pid 2492
13:10:41 worker.3 | started with pid 2495
```

Then, when i enqueue a job using the above code, sometimes, rather randomly i get

```
13:15:55 worker.1 | work
13:15:55 worker.3 | work
```

Here, 'work' indicates that the job is being executed. And i receive a duplicate push notification. If i check the delayed_jobs table i see only one, locked, job. Still, 2 workers are picking it up.

**UPDATE 2**
Here are some logs from Rails

```
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2014-02-02 17:42:37.813835' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2014-02-02 13:42:37.813853') OR locked_by = 'host:positive-definite-fakta-vbox pid:4114') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (4.8ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2014-02-02 17:42:37.772102' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2014-02-02 13:42:37.772130') OR locked_by = 'host:positive-definite-fakta-vbox pid:4118') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE "delayed_jobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE  [["id", 537]]
(0.4ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET "locked_at" = '2014-02-02 17:42:37.844545', "locked_by" = 'host:positive-definite-fakta-vbox pid:4118', "updated_at" = '2014-02-02 17:42:37.954756' WHERE "delayed_jobs"."id" = 537
(0.6ms)  COMMIT
(3.0ms)  BEGIN
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (7.0ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE "delayed_jobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE  [["id", 537]]
(0.4ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET "locked_at" = '2014-02-02 17:42:37.869191', "locked_by" = 'host:positive-definite-fakta-vbox pid:4114', "updated_at" = '2014-02-02 17:42:37.997562' WHERE "delayed_jobs"."id" = 537
(0.8ms)  COMMIT
Device Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "devices".* FROM "devices" WHERE "devices"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "18"]]
Device Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "devices".* FROM "devices" WHERE "devices"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "18"]]
```

As can be seen, both workers get to do the job( 'Device Load...' is the actual work ).

In the delayed_jobs table there is a single entry, locked by:

```
host:positive-definite-fakta-vbox pid:4114
```

What i don't really get is that the above seems like a perfectly normal, highly likely scenario. The only thing happening is that two workers poll the job_queue at just about the same time. Nothing strange about that i guess...but of course the result is disastrous.
How come that the select for update statement:

```
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE "delayed_jobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE  [["id", 537]]
```

is not checking that the job is not already locked? The regular queue-polling seems to do just that.

Comment: How do you know delayed job isn't obtaining a lock?  That seems very unlikely.  Are you seeing duplicate push notifications?

Comment: Yes. I'm seeing duplicate push messages. Also, i can monitor Foreman locally and see 2 workers picking up the job. I'm thinking there is probably something wrong with my local setup...but i can't figure out what.